# List of sample arrangements at a given Wilcoxon / Mann-Whitney test statistic

Tags: algorithms, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, combinatorics

Consider a Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test statistic, either in the form

(i) "W = sum of ranks in sample A"; or in the form

(ii) "sum of ranks in sample A - the minimum possible sum of ranks in sample A", or equivalently "U = the number of times a value in sample 1 exceeds a value in sample 2".

**How would I generate a list of all possible sample arrangements (e.g. the specific ranks in sample A or some equivalent from which that could be computed) at a given value of the statistic (in either form)?**

If I have $n_A=3, n_B=4$, I might specify either $W=10$ or $U = 4$ (the same thing, since $W = U + 6$ as the value I want to see all samples for; a solution for either is fine.

As an example of what I seek, at $n_A=3, n_B=4$ the possible ranks in sample A are:

```
 W
 6: {1, 2, 3},
 7: {1, 2, 4}, 
 8: {1, 2, 5}, {1, 3, 4}, 
 9: {1, 2, 6}, {1, 3, 5}, {2, 3, 4}, 
10: {1, 2, 7}, {1, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 5}, 
11: {1, 3, 7}, {1, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 6}, {2, 4, 5}, 
12: {1, 4, 7}, {1, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 7}, {2, 4, 6}, {3, 4, 5}, 
13: {1, 5, 7}, {2, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 6}, {3, 4, 6}, 
14: {1, 6, 7}, {2, 5, 7}, {3, 4, 7}, {3, 5, 6}, 
15: {2, 6, 7}, {3, 5, 7}, {4, 5, 6}, 
16: {3, 6, 7}, {4, 5, 7}, 
17: {4, 6, 7}, 
18: {5, 6, 7}
```

I'd like a way to specify "nA=3, nB=4, W=10", (or an equivalent), say and get
"`{1, 2, 7}, {1, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 5}`" or something equivalent to it back.

I can come up with brute force approaches of course but I don't think that's feasible in the larger sample sizes.

[For my particular application, it happens that $n_A=n_B$ and I'm mainly interested in cases between about $n_i=10$ to perhaps $n_i=40$ or so, so if either fact makes life significantly easier, feel free to use it. If it's doable at say samples of 25 but not at 40, that would still be useful.]

R packages or code would be especially helpful, but I can code, so an algorithm would be fine and would probably be more generally useful.

Indeed, even some pointers would help.

Comment: To frame it in a non-statistical language: you want to specify $n$, $N$, and $W$ and get all subsets $S$ of $\{1, 2, \ldots N\}$ such that there are exactly $n$ elements in $S$ and they sum to $W$. Is that correct?

Comment: @amoeba yes .... though I posted that so long ago I no longer recall exactly what I was trying to do with it. I expect this sort of calculation might be more broadly useful to some other people, so it's probably worth keeping around on the off-chance it gets an answer. Actually, phrased the way you have it, it's a suitable question for some other sites, like math.SE or perhaps one of the computer science (does theoretical take that sort of algorithm question?)

Comment: Once reformulated as above, it sounds 100% like a computer science question to me. But I am not familiar with the relevant SE sites.

Comment: The family of ?wilcox (? =d,q,p, or r) in base R might help but I think they are written in C++ or Fortran. The documentation does refer to cwilcox which looks just like what you want but it does not seem to be documented.